# Doesn't work MasterPage event when fireing the Required validation in child page

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, master-pages

I have a Master page in my ASP.net web site. And here I have a Button. It will navigates to wecomePage. Here is the code behind.

```
protected void ImageButtonShortcut1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  Response.Redirect("welcomePage.aspx", true);
  //Server.Transfer("welcomePage.aspx", true);
}
```

Now I have a childpage which inherits above master. Inside the child page I used a TextBox with `Required validation`.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Model" runat="server">  </asp:TextBox>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" 
                         ControlToValidate="TextBox_Model" ErrorMessage="Model Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Scenario : When User navigates to above child page and without entering anything to that Text box, he is trying to hit Master page Button for return  to `WelcomePage`.

Unfortunately It doesn't allow to navigate, since user hasn't filled the Required field. How can I overcome this problem? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not using ValidationGroup for the RequiredFieldValidator for their correspondent Button. try using that

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" 
                ValidationGroup="WelcomePageTxtBox" ControlToValidate="TextBox_Model" ErrorMessage="Model Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator> 
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="WelcomePageTxtBox" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is happening for every control is set to CausesValidation Property set to True.

from [Required Field validator and Page Valid methods](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/03/15/page-isvalid-and-validate.aspx)

> The Validate method iterates through all enabled validation controls
>   on the page and validates them. This event occurs after the Load event
>   in the page lifecycle.
>
> If the control that raised the event has a ValidationGroup specified,
>   then only enabled validator controls that belong to the same
>   ValidationGroup are validated by calling the
>   Page.Validate(ValidationGroup) overload method. As mentioned
>   previously, this is done automatically for controls that have the
>   CausesValidation property set to true.

1. Specifying validation group will only get validated during page lifecycle

in code behind  you can do like this

```
protected void button2_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(!page.isValid)
 //show errors
}
else
{
 // do some stuffs
}
```