# how to escape from RequiredFiledValidator control

Tags: c#

i have a form consist of the textbox and dropdown list controls and a i have applied RequiredFieldValidator on all of them . now I want that if someone visit that page and then he change his mind and wants to go other pages by clicking on any other link on Master page so this RequiredField Validator doesn't allow him and ask him to fill the values. so how can i do it so that user can go to other links on master page and this validation should trigger only when I try to update or add another record in Database. i am using this using APS.NET with C# and bootstrap 4

plz guide

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Put a cancel button on page and set it's 'causesValidation' property to false :

```
<asp:Button CausesValidation="False" ....... />
```

Comment: i have a home link which do exit user from that page but i want that when user directly click on Master page link so he can navigate.

Comment: You have to use the ValidationGroup. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117801/doesnt-work-masterpage-event-when-fireing-the-required-validation-in-child-page